# Android: Drawing stretched/squished in bitmap/canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

Our application has several types of widgets. They are all drawn onto square canvases. They are draggable and resizable. Some of the widgets are thin or short, and when they are placed close together, the transparent part overlaps the visible part of another widget completely, making them hard to select.

I need to remove the transparent parts and draw the widgets onto a background correctly sized with no extra. This, for some reason has been harder than I expected.

Example of a widget with the problem. This is a different widget, but to illustrate how it is on a square background. See how the corners are nicely rounded?

[image: Square Canvas for Widget]

Resizing the bitmap to be rectangular, makes the corners stretched and the font squished/stretched:
[image: Rect Canvas for Widget]

Do you know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yayyyy!! I figured it out!

In onDraw(Canvas canvas):

Old code:

```
canvas.scale((float) width, (float) height);
```

New Code:

```
// Scale square, so nothing gets stretched or squished
canvas.scale((float) width, (float) width);

// Crops the canvas
canvas.clipRect(0f, 0f, 1f, .33f);
```

Then I just make sure that all my rects are only using the top 1/3 of the canvas

[image]